# In Force.con IDE - Error while deploying to Server

Tags: force.com, ide

I am getting following error while deploying metadata to Force.com Server

[image: Error while deploying metadata using Force.com IDE]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is presented (not just during deployments) when Java7 (1.7) is installed. Ran into it myself this morning when trying to set up a new project.

Removing Java7 from the machine so that Eclipse cannot reference it, should revert you back to having just the 1.6 JDK available and you'll be back in business.

Worst case, remove all installed versions of Java and then download & install JDK 1.6 again. If you're running a 32-bit version of Eclipse be sure to install the 32-bit JDK.

Comment: I'm getting this one sometime when I create new project - project is created, can't download or create any metadata files because of this error, restart of Eclipse and it works again.

Comment: Fully removing JDK1.7 isn't technically required (it wasn't an option for me) - if you edit eclipse.ini (or forceide.ini) to include the well-documented "-vm" option, and then make sure that the Eclipse "Installed JREs" tab in Preferences > Java doesn't include any 1.7 JREs, you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

launch your IDE with the clean option

“C:\Program Files\MyEclipse 6.6\eclipse\eclipse.exe” -clean

Comment: and if that doesn't work, try downgrading your java version  to 1.6

Answer (score 2):

As explained by others this happenns when JRE is updated from 1.6 to a higher version. The way i handle is by going to Window -> preferences in ForceIDE top menu.

You will get a dialog window, Click on Java ->Installed JRE and uncheck jre7. Restart ForceIDE it should work.
[image]