# Deleting a Class with IDE - cannot delete from Production?

Tags: apex, trigger, ide, class

When trying to delete a Class using IDE (simply right click and delete, and confirming I want it deleted in SF as well), it fails with the following screenshot.  I have seen a couple posts via Google search that show people having this problem, but I'm not seeing a solution.

I am trying to cleanup.  We have consolidated many classes (and triggers) into single classes/triggers, and now have old classes commented out with no code actually running - we'd like to remove them so our list of classes/triggers is clean/shorter.

[image: Failed Delete in IDE]

Trying the same in Sandbox:  Worked fine.  I tried deleting from Production AFTER deleting in Sandbox, and it still failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot delete a class in production directly. You will need delete the class from your sandbox and then deploy the deletions to your production org. When you deploy from sandbox to production, the missing classes will come up in red and you can choose to deploy these deletions to Production.

If there was a dependency on that class in another piece of code, you may have to deploy a version of that class or trigger with the dependency commented and then deploy the deletion.

If you are using the Force.com Migration tool, you can deploy the deletions using destructiveChanges.xml

Comment: WHOA.  I was not aware of that.  Going to try that ASAP.  Makes sense given the Sandbox-Production relationship...

Comment: Great.  Since I test deleted a class in Sandbox using IDE, it's not showing up as a delete-available class for deployment now (so I'm guessing it's stuck in Production forever unless simply creating a new class by the same name fixes it- I'll try that).

Comment: Have you tried deploying the entire classes folder to production after carrying out the deletion?  Eclipse should figure out the differences between the two folders.

Comment: @techtrekker , deleting the Class in Sandbox does nothing except delete it.  It does not show up in the list of classes (red or otherwise)   :-(

Comment: @BobBuzzard , no, since I cannot delete in Production anyway, but I will try now....  did not work.  I deleted the class in IDE, then on the Classes folder, right click, Force.com, Save To Server, no change.   (though it "succeeded" in it's Save supposedly).

Comment: For future readers: I wrote a bit of a walkthrough on this topic that includes recreating a class just so you can deploy a delete changeset from the IDE: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8209053/864030