# Deleting Apex Triggers from Production

Tags: apex, trigger

I have to delete (not inactive) a trigger from Production.

I have gone through this link already

[Deleting Triggers/Classes from Production](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5776/deleting-triggers-classes-from-production)

Mohith has mentioned that we have to set the Status as "Deleted"

But as per this Salesforce link

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006188&type=1

We will be able to set the status as only "Inactive" for triggers and "Deleted" for Apex classes.

So how will I be able to delete an apex trigger ?

Comment: I've linked this question as a duplicate of the another question that contains a technique for easily deleting stuff from production. I use this technique all the time, and it's pretty straight-forward. You just need to change ApexClass to ApexTrigger, and change the `members` to the trigger you want to delete.

Comment: @AaronWilfred - I think you are reading it incorrectly. It says "Or to disable the trigger change it to Inactive" so you can inactivate a trigger in addition to delete and activate. An apex class cannot be made inactive. It can only be deleted or activated. The example you linked to will work fine. Did you even try it?

Comment: Tx Eric..Since this is a prd I wanted to check it out first. Tx again