# Deleting Apex Classes & Triggers from Production

Tags: apex

I am trying to delete some of my production code.

I am using VS Code and when I push the following to Prod:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexTrigger xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>36.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Deleted</status>
</ApexTrigger>
```

I receive the following error:

```
INVALID_OPERATION: INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations
```

How do I delete Apex code from production? To my knowledge, you go into the metadata of your production code and change the status from "Active" to "Deleted".

Comment: I really just want to know how to delete classes

Comment: Have you checked post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5776/deleting-triggers-classes-from-production ?