# Is Force.com IDE v.29 complaint with JRE 7?

Tags: force.com, ide

Is Force.com IDE v.29 complaint with JRE 7?

There were a lot of issues with Force.com IDE complaincy with JRE 7 (I am talking about Force.com IDE v.28 and issues like
[Problems Installing Force.com IDE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7320/problems-installing-force-com-ide) and [In Force.con IDE - Error while deploying to Server](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5161/in-force-con-ide-error-while-deploying-to-server) and similar.

On official page http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE they claim that they have included in Winter '14 release

**Java support**

**Added support for Java 6 and 7**

It could take a lot of time to uninstall existing version or Force.com IDE and install new one, so I am not sure if I want to try it myself.
So I am just curious.
Did anyone try it? Can anyone confirm that all the issues have gone away?

Answer (score 1):

I have win7 64bit, java 7 update 51, kepler service release 1 and Force.com v.29. So far so good, except sometimes Home and End buttons stop working in Eclipse. That's it.

Sorry, forgot to add about another laptop.
Win8 64bit, java 7 update 25, kepler release and Force.com v.29. So far so good. No problem with Home and End buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Mac and switched from the previous version of the buggy Force.com IDE to the newer Force.com IDE Plugin for Eclipse. The crashing of the old standalone IDE is no longer something that happens, although there isn't much of an improvement beyond that (the autocomplete seems to work better, that's about it).

I found Java 7 seems to work, but if you already have Java 6 for the older IDE I don't see any reason you'd need to upgrade your Java just to test. You can install a newer version of Eclipse and install the plugin alongside your current IDE and take it for a test drive.

Comment: JRE 6 has a lot security issues exploited, I wouldn't use JRE 6 if I could

Answer (score 0):

The latest eclipse version has been buggy.  Also I have not see any improvements on the force.com plugin.  I've switched to BrainEngine Salesforce IDE and my development.  The experience has been great so far.  Now I use eclipse for Java development and BrainEngine for Salesforce.